# How do I change the style of all rows in the selected range?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2013

I want to create a macro that will highlight all rows of a selected range of cells. E.g. If I select cells A1 and B3 I want the macro to highlight rows 1 and 3. Currently I have the following macro which is able to highlight a row from a single cell, but I don't know how to expand it to highlight the rows of all selected cells:

```
Sub Macro1()
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Style = "Good"
End Sub
```

Comment: ActiveCell.Resize(2).EntireRow.Style = "Good"

Comment: @DeanBDean that just highlights 2 rows at and below the lowest of the selected cells.

Comment: Whoops, I misread what you were asking. Replace `ActiveCell` with `Selection`

Comment: @DeanBDean Should make it as Answer, probably with selection type checking first (only apply to Range type: `typename(selection) = "Range"`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest this as your sub.

```
Sub Macro1()
     If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
          Selection.EntireRow.Style = "Good"
     End If
End Sub
```

ActiveCell is only going to return the top left cell within the Selection. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa141477%28v=office.10%29.aspx). Also, thanks to PatrickK for the suggestion about checking the typename, I am embarrassed to say I was unaware of the [TypeName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5422sfdf%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) function before now.